# WYGWAM/CKEditor Skin

Tags: custom-fields, wygwam, fieldtype, pixelandtonic, wysiwyg

I’ve got something here that is absolutely not critical, but it's bugging me and I’ve been encouraged to post it here to see if anyone can help out.

I am trying to change the skin of WYGWAM to one I found for CKEditor that I really enjoy ([Moono](http://ckeditor.com/addon/moono), which I believe is the default now), but when I try to do that, the WYGWAM field will no longer load. I found what I thought was the appropriate place to change the skin in third_party/wygwam/helper.php. And I uploaded the skin to themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/skins. But no joy. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is what I’m changing in helper.php:

```
public static function base_config()
{
    return array_merge(array(
        'skin'               => 'wygwam2',
        'toolbarCanCollapse' => 'n',
        'dialog_backgroundCoverOpacity' => 0,
        'entities_processNumerical' => 'y',
        'forcePasteAsPlainText' => 'y'
    ), self::default_config_settings());
}
```

Obviously, I’m changing 'wygmwa2' to 'moono'.

Here is what the field looks like before trying to change the skin: [before](http://buzzingpixelcreative.com/web-stuff/eese/2013-03-11/wygwam-default.png)

And here is what it looks like when I change the skin in helper.php: [after](http://buzzingpixelcreative.com/web-stuff/eese/2013-03-11/wygwam-trying-new-theme.png)

Additionally, after playing around with helper.php, I realized I could change skins on a per configuration basis in the advanced settings and I tried that, but experienced the same problem.

The field is obviously failing to initialize. Any ideas, anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be somewhat more simple.  Can you go to your Wygwam editor configuration, under Advanced Settings, in the drop-down, choose Skin and follow those instructions.  Let's see if that helps?

If that doesn't work, please check your dev console for any JS errors and report them here.  Thank you!

Edit to add: this is quite an old post, but you might try what's in here if the above doesn't work: https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/use_office2003_skin_in_wygwam

Comment: I agree with Lisa here. Have you checked your debugger for any JS errors? It will likely give you some clues. Most likely there are some JS or CSS path issues or something like that.

Comment: Hi Lisa, I didn’t explain it very well, but I did try the drop down configuration. I tried again and got the same thing. I tried with just the skin name, I tried with the path to the skin, I tried with skin name with path after comma (both with and without trailing slash), and I tried skin name with hard server path after comma.

I can’t find anything called dev console in the CP. I checked the developer log and got no results found. I also enabled output profiler, and as far as I can tell there’s nothing weird going on.

Comment: Your dev console is a browser feature.  In Chrome, for instance, right click and choose "Inspect Element" - then click Console. Then load the publish page and see if there are any errors there. :)

Comment: "*slaps head*"

doh

BRB...

Comment: Here is what I’m getting: http://buzzingpixelcreative.com/web-stuff/eese/2013-03-13/dev-console01.png

Comment: TJ - did you check what version that skin was made for?  I mean of CKEditor - is it for 3 or 4?